# Difference between cat and fold unix command

Tags: unix, cat

I would like to know difference between below 2 commands `cat` and `fold` commands? I just 
   used `fold` command and it acts like `cat` command.

```
fold file1.txt
cat fold.txt (both are using to display the contents of the file)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fold` command wraps text when `cat` displays text without wrapping :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check their manpages

```
man fold
fold - wrap each input line to fit in specified width

man cat
cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output
```

Appearantly with `fold` you can specify a width, whereas no such option exists in `cat`

Answer (score 0):

`fold` - Filter for folding lines. This breaks the lines to have a maximum of x width column position (or bytes).

`Example` : fold -5 myfile.txt > newfile.txt

In the above command, this would fold the lines of myfile.txt to 5 character width and re-route the results to the file newfile.txt

`cat` - Allows you to read the contents of file

`Example` : cat file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt

Reads file1.txt and file2.txt and combines those files to make file3.txt.